# populate nested array of objects mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have been trying to populate products in my Cart.
My Cart model is -

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
  quantity: Number
});
const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  products: [ProductSchema]
});
```

I am trying to get the cart value like this -

```
let getCart = async (userId) => {
  let res = await Cart.find({ userId: userId }).populate('products.product')
  return res;
};
```

Output -

```
{
  userId: xyz,
  products:[
    product: null,
    quantity:1
  ]
}
```

Expected Result -

```
{ 
  userId: xyz,
  products:[
    product: {
      name: 'product name', 
      description:'',
      ...
    },
    quantity:1
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose populating array of subdocuments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470823/mongoose-populating-array-of-subdocuments)

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate only `products` and select `product` to show from the populated array.

Answer (score -1):

Just populating product is enough I guess.

```
let getCart = async (userId) => {
  let res = await Cart.find({ userId: userId }).populate('products')
  return res;
};
```